# TeamCity - Disable artifacts being sent back to build server

Tags: build-process, teamcity, build-automation, teamcity-7.0

At the end of a TeamCity build, it sends the artifacts back to the TC server. I don't need this to happen because my build script is pushing them to S3 where our web servers pick the payload up from. Is there a way I can disable them from being sent back, it's taking 1 min 30 seconds just for that step because the files are so large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be most easily accomplished by clearing out the `Artifact paths` field in the *General Settings* of you build configuration.  TeamCity should only be saving the things that are included there (in addition to a few internal reporting items.)